# DECLARE *** NO SCROLL CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, оптимизация, orm

Есть `QuerySet` для выборки товаров. В его результате, получаются 3 запроса вида

```
DECLARE "_django_curs_140593907361344_sync_2" 
NO SCROLL CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR 
SELECT ••• FROM "product" ORDER BY "product"."title" ASC
```

Как с этим бороться? ибо они самые тяжелые

Answer (score 0):

Проверить наличие индексов в таблице product. Индексы хорошо ускоряют выполнение sql запросов.

Comment: индекс по указанному полю уже существует